# Can a UK citizen residing in UK sponsor a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation, cuban-citizens

I recently successfully sponsored a UK long term visitor visa for my partner, who is a Cuban citizen residing in Cuba. We plan for him to make several 3-4 month visits to the UK during the validity period of the visa, and I would like to be able to travel to Europe with him (main destination would be Italy, possibly also France or Spain) for say 1-2 weeks during at least one of those visits (ie travelling from and returning to the UK).

AFAIK the following documents are required for him to apply for a Schengen visa from Cuba:

- return ticket (or booking) or evidence that the applicant has their own means of transport
- proof that the applicant has sufficient means of subsistence
- supporting documentation in relation to the applicant's social and professional status
- health insurance covering a minimum of €30,000
- proof of accommodation

When he applied for his UK visa, I provided an invitation letter and financially sponsored all his travel, accommodation, and maintenance costs. Is it possible for a UK citizen to do the same for a Schengen application, or does a sponsor have to be an EU citizen?

Answer (score 1):

For [italy](/questions/tagged/italy) (as seen on [Il Visto Per l'Italia](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en#BMQuestionario)), the required pieces for a Cuban citizen in Cuba are as follows :

> [...]
>
> - proof of accommodation (hotel booking, Declaration of hospitality, declaration whereby accommodation costs shall be borne by the person inviting) [( View )](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/Moduli/it/DICHIARAZIONEALLOGGIOGARANZIA.PDF)

The linked PDF leads to a *PROOF OF SPONSORSHIP AND/OR PRIVATE ACCOMMODATION* (*DICHIARAZIONE GARANZIA E/O ALLOGGIO*) that you seem to be able to fill as a UK national living in the UK, by ticking

> dichiaro di farmi carico delle sue spese di sostentamento durante il soggiorno/*declare
> being able to bear his\her living costs during the abovementioned period of stay*

And the other relevant boxes after that

Now it seems to require a *fideiussione bancaria* (bank guarentee), where a bank will lock a [sum of money](https://www.insuranceitaly.it/surety-insurance-or-bank-guarantee-for-foreigners-entering-italy-which-to-choose/?lang=en) for 90 days in case the foreigner needs it.

You can only contract it as a resident of Italy, so I'd be inclined to contact the Italian embassy in either the UK or Cuba for a definite answer if it's needed for your specific case

---

For [france](/questions/tagged/france), there isn't any specific form/letter to provide for that, but I think you could just join a cover letter for your sponsorship, especially as their partner, this would seem perfectly reasonable

There is a [*attestation d'accueil*](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2191), but this only applies to French residents that are hosting the foreigner

---

For [spain](/questions/tagged/spain), the [visa page](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/lahabana/es/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/index.aspx?scco=Cuba&scd=166&scca=Visados&scs=Visado+de+estancia+(visado+Schengen)) for the Spanish embassy in Cuba :

> **Documentos que acrediten el motivo del viaje y las condiciones de la estancia, la disponibilidad de medios económicos suficientes, y que permitan establecer la intención del solicitante de abandonar el espacio Schengen antes de la caducidad del visado.**

From Google Translate :

> Documents that prove the reason for the trip and the conditions of the stay, the availability of sufficient financial means, and that allow establishing the applicant's intention to leave the Schengen area before the expiration of the visa.

Again, that would let me believe, that you could just join a cover letter for your sponsorship

Comment: Thank you - we are long term, long distance partners, but not married or permanently living together. Do you think that lack of permanence makes any difference to sponsorship?

Comment: @Traveller I wouldn't really think so